# SMS sending permission on Active Android device

Tags: android, sms

I'm a newbie with android development. So far I have developed an application which uses `SMSManager`.

I'm testing my application on an active device when it reaches `smsManager.sendTextMessage` it throws exception of `android.premission.SEND_SMS`.
I know that I have to get device permission.

My Question is:
Can I send SMS while uploading application right from IDE, or have to install .apk manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add the following permissions in your Manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
```

Answer (score 1):

If you install the application via debugging/IDE/ADB it will automatically get the permissions you require in your manifest.

So: Yes! When run on the device through the debugger, the application will be able to send test messages.

Bonus information: If you do "stuff" that the application doesn't have the proper permissions for, the debugger will give you exceptions and hints to what is wrong.

Comment: Very well, these are sure reasons, of actual and test devices. Thanks :) (Y)